# adding edit functionality in 1 page instead of 2

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, knockout.js

I wanted to know if its possible for me to have a table where I am displaying data , and at the same time if I click the edit button I could edit certain fields on that table instead of going to a different page and editing them. To get started I have a table which shows data like this.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: moneyborrowedtable">
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="formatDate:$data.INSERT_DT"></span></td>
                <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:$data.symbol"></span> <span data-bind="text:$data.Amount"></span></td>
                <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:$data.Interest"></span> %</td>
                <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:$data.Loantime"> Days</span></td>
                <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:$data.StatusDescription"></span></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <span href="#" data-bind="if: ($data.borrowed_amount > 0 || $data.status == 0)">View</span>
                  <!-- <a href="#" data-bind="if: $data.borrowed_amount > 0, click: $root.getMoneyBorrowedForPaying">Pay</a> -->
                  <a href="#" data-bind="ifnot: ($data.borrowed_amount > 0 || $data.status == 0), click: $root.editMoneyBorrowed , click: $root.goForIt" ><span style="padding: 5px 10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> 
                  <a href="#" data-bind="ifnot: ($data.borrowed_amount > 0 || $data.status == 0), click: $root.deleteMoneyBorrowed"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I am using knockout js to display the data. So when the person clicks editMoneyBorrowed , I take them to a differnt page where they edit, the information for that is here.
Controller function where it goes to first.

```
public function editMoneyRequest($id, $viewonly) {
        $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->model('admin_page');
                $this->load->model('localization');
        $this->load->model('moneyrequest_page');
        $this->load->model('user_profile');

                /* Yhdenmukaistetaan sidebarien ulkonäköä. Jussi 13.07.2014 */
                $facebookId = $this->Facebook->getUser();
                $sidebarData = array(
                    'userName' => $this->user_profile->getUserName(), 
                    'facebookId' => $facebookId, 
                    'caller' => 'getMyLoans'
                );

        $this->load->view('header', $this->history->getPreviousPageInArray());
        $this->load->view('moneyexchange_sidebar_view', $sidebarData);

                $userId = $this->user_profile->getUserId();

        $data = array(
                        'viewonly' => $viewonly,
                        'userId' => $userId,
                        'userName' => $sidebarData['userName'],
                        'currencyList' => $this->localization->getCurrencyList(),
                        'preValues' => $this->admin_page->getPreValues(),
                        'assuranceList' => $this->localization->getTextParamValues($userId, 'money_request', 'assurance_code'),
                        'providerList' => $this->localization->getTextParamValues($userId, 'money_request', 'provider_code'),
                        'paymenttermList' => $this->localization->getTextParamValues($userId, 'money_loan', 'payment_term'),
                        'moneyRequest' => $this->moneyrequest_page->getMoneyRequestWithStatusDescription($id)
                );
        $this->load->view("request_money_edit_view", $data);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
```

And this is the html page for editing.

```
<div class="well">

        <?php

        if(validation_errors() != false) 
        { 
            echo '<div class="form-group has-error">';
                echo'<ul>';
                    echo validation_errors('<li class="control-label">', '</li>');
                echo'</ul>';
            echo '</div>';   
        }

        /* form-horizontal */
        $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', "data-bind" => "submit: verifyLoginToLoanersClub");
        echo form_open('moneyrequest/saveEditedMoneyRequest', $attributes); 
        /*
        if ($viewonly == 'false') {
            echo '<h4 class="pull-left>'. lang("offer_edit_money_request_title") . '</h4>';
        } else {
            echo '<h4 class="pull-left>'. lang("offer_view_money_request_title") . '</h4>';
        }
        */
        ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4 class="pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_edit_money_request_title"); ?></h4>
    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->StatusDescription; ?>" disabled="true">
    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
</div> <!-- row -->

        <input type="hidden" id="request_money_userid" name="userId" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="request_money_username" name="userName" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="request_money_provider_id" name="provider_id" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->provider_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="request_money_provider_name" name="provider_name" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->provider_name; ?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->ID; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->status; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="Owner" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->Owner; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="loan_orig_id" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->loan_orig_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="ORIG_ID" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->ORIG_ID; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice_orig_id" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->invoice_orig_id; ?>">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="<?php if(form_error('amount')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">

            <div class="control-label pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_of_amount");?></div>
            <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->Amount; ?>" name="amount">
            <!-- <select name="amount" id="request_money_select_amount" class="form-control"> -->
            <?php /*
                foreach ($preValues as $prevalue) 
                {
                    if ($prevalue->Type == 1) 
                    {                      
                        echo '<option value="' . $prevalue->Value . '"'; 
                        if ($moneyRequest[0]->Amount == $prevalue->Value) 
                        {
                            echo ' selected';
                        }
                        echo '>' . $prevalue->Value . '</option>';
                    }
                } */
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="<?php if(form_error('currency')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">

            <div class="control-label pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_of_currency");?></div>

            <select name="currency" id="request_money_select_currency" class="form-control">
            <?php
                foreach ($currencyList as $currency)
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $currency->ID. '"';
                    if($currency->ID==$moneyRequest[0]->Currency)
                    {
                        echo 'selected';
                    }
                    echo '>' . $currency->Abbreviation .'';     
                    echo  '</option>';          
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="<?php if(form_error('interest')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
            <div class="control-label pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_of_intrest");?></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->Interest; ?>" name="interest">
            <!-- <select name="interest" id="request_money_select_interest" class="form-control"> -->
            <?php /*
                foreach ($preValues as $prevalue) 
                {
                    if ($prevalue->Type == 2) 
                    {
                        echo '<option value="' . $prevalue->Value . '"'; 
                        if ($moneyRequest[0]->Interest == $prevalue->Value) 
                        {
                            echo ' selected';
                        }
                        echo '>' . $prevalue->Value . '</option>'; 
                    }
                } */
            ?>
            <!-- </select> -->
        </div>

    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
</div> <!-- row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="<?php if(form_error('available')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">

            <div class="control-label pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_of_avail");?></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" data-provide="datepicker" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" value="<?php echo $moneyRequest[0]->Available; ?>" name="available">
        </div>

    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">

         <div class="<?php if(form_error('loantime')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
            <div class="control-label pull-left"><?php echo lang("offer_loan_time_days");?></div>
            <select name="loantime" id="offer_money_select_loantime" class="form-control">

                <?php

                foreach ($preValues as $prevalue) 
                {
                    if ($prevalue->Type == 3) 
                    {
                        /*echo'<option value="'. $prevalue->ID . '">' . $prevalue->Value . '</option>'; */
                        echo '<option value="' . $prevalue->Value . '"'; 
                        if ($moneyRequest[0]->Loantime == $prevalue->Value) 
                        {
                            echo ' selected';
                        }
                        echo '>' . $prevalue->Value . '</option>'; 
                    }
                }

                ?>

            </select>
        </div>



 </div>


    </form> <!-- Form Horizontal -->   
    </div> <!-- well -->
```

So after this step is done, I try to post this information to a contoller function and save it in the database.
So my main concern is that this is more then 2 steps , and I want to do everything on that table itself, I dont mind editing the data under each td class of the first table, but I really want the users not to go to another page.
So I am looking for someone to advice me on how to make this extra edit part done in that table itself or maybe under the table. I only want to edit is AMOUNT, INTEREST and LOAN PERIOD in the table, I dont need the other things. Please do tell me in steps :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple model of editing which might be useful:-

```
<span data-bind="text:firstName,visible:!editable()">
</span>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:firstName,visible:editable"/ >
<button data-bind="click:editMe,text:editButtonText"></button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fvnb946/18/

Gist:
editable observable is enabled when you click the button and based on that portions of UI are hidden or shown.

Comment: Thanks alot this is useful !!!! but then again I cannot accept the answer since it just helps in editing and I need to push this edited data from observable to database, I am still trying to do it, but will keep this in mind!

Comment: Let us say on finish  of edit, collect all observables and then pass it to server using ajax or form post.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a small bit of code myself for this. What I think you want is be able to click a td and edit the data inside of this? Without being redirected to another editing page? If so, this can be all done easily with Jquery and CI.

At first once you click on a TD you want to grab the Thead that co-responds with it. You can grab the Thead with the following Jquery.
You also want to turn the TD's you want to be able to edit into contenteditable like follow":

```
`<td contenteditable="true"></td>`


 $("td").click(function(e){
    $("table thead tr th").eq($value.index());
 });
```

This will probably require a little bit of work among your side of making sure the Thead turns into the database column. (I created a smaller version of phpmyadmin so my Theads are column names directly)

Now after you've grabbed this, you will probably need to know which ID of the table you're trying to edit. I did this by giving each TR a data-attribute with the ID of the record I'm editing.

Now you want to edit the data once you "post" your new input. So far we have the column name and ID of the record we're editing. All that's missing is the table. Again, for me I didn't need to do this because my URL responds to which field I'm editing. I suppose it wouldn't be too difficult for you to find a way of your own to do such thing (Perhaps send the table name (encrypted) to the view).

Now you want to post the data being send to your handler. You can do this by using the Jquery     `$.post()` function.

```
 $("td").click(function(e){
    var $id =$(this).parent().data('id');
    $('td[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
        // trap the return key being pressed
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $value = $(this);
            var $field =  $("table thead tr th").eq($value.index()).html();
            $valuenew = $value.html();

            $.post( "URL_to_post_to", 
            { id: $id, newvalue: $valuenew, field: $field , table : "users"} );
            //The code below displays a loading screen and then refreshes the page.
            $(".se-pre-con").css("display", "");
            setTimeout(function(){
                location.reload(true);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

This is how I handle my data-editing. Now to grab the post you do the exact same as always in CI: `$this->input->post('id')` or `$this->input->post('table')`

Comment: hey, do you have any file or js fiddle of this example, I read and understood but might be super hard to implement.

Comment: Or you could help me rewrite my functions ? :)

Comment: I will edit my post later tonight to give a full example of a quick way of doing this. Check my reply in about 3-4 hours and I would be home and posted a new awnser.

Comment: okay will be waiting for your answer, and thanks for all the help :)